# NoReverseMatch at /project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django. I created a simple createview and then tried the updateview likewise but I got the NoReverseMatch Error. I tried many ways suggested online but still they didnt seem to work.
This is the screenshot of the error I am getting [NoReverseMatchError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xdA.png)

Below are my files

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from mapp import views 

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
url(r'^blogs/$',views.BlogsView.as_view(),name='blog'),
url(r'^project/$',views.ProjectListView.as_view(),name='project_list'), 
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(),name='project_detail'),
url(r'^project/create/$',views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(),name='project_create'),
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProjectUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView
from mapp.models import Project
from mapp.forms import ProjectCreateForm,ProjectUpdateForm

# Create your views here.

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name='about.html'

class BlogsView(TemplateView):
    template_name='blogs.html'

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model=Project

class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Project

class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model=Project
    form_class=ProjectCreateForm
    redirect_field_name='mapp/project_detail.html'

class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model=Project
    form_class=ProjectUpdateForm
    redirect_field_name='mapp/project_detail.html'
```

Project_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<h1>Project Details</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>{{project.pname}}</h2>
        <img src="{{project.pimage.url}}"></img>
        <h2>{{project.ptech}}</h2>
        <h2>{{project.pdetails}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <p><a href="{%url 'update' pk=self.pk %}">Update</a>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from mapp.models import Project

class ProjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model=Project
        fields=('pname','pimage','ptech','pdetails')

class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model=Project
        fields=('pname','pimage','ptech','pdetails')
```

Project_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form class="project-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your kwargs are not being passed to the view. Try changing `self.id` in your template to `project.id`

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<h1>Project Details</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>{{project.pname}}</h2>
        <img src="{{project.pimage.url}}"></img>
        <h2>{{project.ptech}}</h2>
        <h2>{{project.pdetails}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <p><a href="{%url 'update' pk=project.pk %}">Update</a>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Also your Detail and Update Views have the same url. Try adding something to make them different like

```
url(r'^project/detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(),name='project_detail'),
url(r'^project/create/$',views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(),name='project_create'),
url(r'^project/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProjectUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
```

Or else it won't find the updateview.

Comment: Thanks Leelum! This removed the error, but its not taking me to update the fields. Its staying on the same page after clicking update button

Comment: Word, check the edit to my answer. I think you need to change your urls.

Comment: try also to use `{%url 'update' project.pk %}` without `pk=`

Comment: Thanks Leelum!...The edit you added to your answer solved the problem! Many thanks :)

Comment: Nice nice. Help me out too and accept the answer :)